# r function for counting specific row of 2 columns

Tags: r

I need help how to compare 2 columns in r studio but only in the first 5 observations

code used  first was

```r
damgeByage<-table(test$Vehicle_Age,test$Vehicle_Damage)
damgeByage
```

which  give   me all 186 observation but only want the first 10 oobservation of both columns
I

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can subset the data with row index

```
 table(test[1:10, c("Vehicle_Age", "Vehicle_Damage")])
```

Answer (score 1):

akrun's answer works or you can also use:

```
table(test$Vehicle_Age[1:10],test$Vehicle_Damage[1:10])
```

the table is also subsettable if you just wanted the first 10 rows of the results:

```
damgeByage<-table(test$Vehicle_Age,test$Vehicle_Damage)
damgeByage[1:10,]
```